# Why does my react button work with an arrow function, but not when I give it a function?

Tags: reactjs

React newbie, I feel like this button should work, it seems to be identical to the standard counter example with a button click, but for some reason the onClick method never executes.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I'm able to write an arrow function and have it called correctly like this:

```
static renderButton() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button className="btn btn-primary" 
              onClick={() => { alert('clicked'); }}>
                Create new paper
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

but if I move it into its own function, it stops working

```
static renderButton() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button className="btn btn-primary" 
              onClick={this.buttonClick}>
                Create new paper
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Full example: https://jsfiddle.net/cjames9001/L86rh9na/

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize that my renderButton method is a static member.

Therefore, I won't have any reference to any of the instance methods. Which explains why my method wasn't being called, it was setting onClick to undefined.

Fixed by making the renderButton method an instance method and calling it as such:

```
renderButton() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button className="btn btn-primary" 
              onClick={this.buttonClick}>
                Create new paper
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}

render() {
    let contents = this.renderButton();
     return (
        <div>
            <h1 id="tabelLabel" >Button works! :)</h1>
            {contents}
        </div>
    );
}
```